# Multithreaded Tasking System fails list iterator not derefercable

Tags: c++, multithreading, list, multitasking

Okay this meight be a bit off for Stack but ill try to keep it as short as possible.

I got thread which takes tasks out of a list and executes them. Simple as this (The worker class has its own thread and runs doTask `m_thread(&Worker::doTask, this)`):

```
void Worker::doTask()
{
    while (m_running)
    {
        auto task = m_tasks.pop_front();
        task->execute();
        if (task->isContinuous())
            m_tasks.push_pack(task);
    }
}
```

The list itself is/should be threadsafe:
Header:

```
class TaskQueue
{
public:
    void push_pack(std::shared_ptr<Task> t);
    std::shared_ptr<Task> pop_front();
private:
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<Task>> m_tasks;
    std::condition_variable m_cond;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    void TaskQueue::push_pack(std::shared_ptr<Task> t)
}
```

Impls of the importand part:

```
void TaskQueue::push_pack(std::shared_ptr<Task> t)
{
    m_tasks.push_back(t);
    //notify that there is one more task, so one thread can work now
    m_cond.notify_one();
}

std::shared_ptr<Task> TaskQueue::pop_front()
{
    //regular lock so noone else acces this area now
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    while (m_tasks.size() == 0)
        m_cond.wait(lock);

    auto task = m_tasks.front();
    m_tasks.pop_front();
    return task;
}
```

last but not least the tasks:

```
class Task
{
public:
    virtual ~Task()
    {
    }
    virtual void execute() = 0;
    virtual bool isContinuous()
    {
        return false;
    };
};
```

So if i try to add this Task:

```
class NetworkRequestTask:public Task
{
public:
    NetworkRequestTask(TaskQueue &q);
    ~NetworkRequestTask();

    void execute() override;
    bool isContinuous() override;
private:
    TaskQueue &m_tasks;
};
```

Impl:

```
NetworkRequestTask::NetworkRequestTask(TaskQueue& q): m_tasks(q)
{
}

NetworkRequestTask::~NetworkRequestTask()
{
}

void NetworkRequestTask::execute()
{
    while(dosomething)
    {
//do something here
    }
}

bool NetworkRequestTask::isContinuous()
{
    return true;
}
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    TaskQueue tasks;
    tasks.push_pack(std::make_shared<NetworkRequestTask>(tasks));
}
```

it gets into a bad state:

```
Expression: list iterator not derefercable
```

I am Confused. This only happens if i override continouse and this only happens at this task. If i add the queue to a other continouse task as reference it does not get into that bad state.

So whats going wrong here and more importand what have i done wrong?

---

As from the comments, i already tried to lock the push_back method which did not change anything to the behaviour. (You can exchange it for a regular mutex it doesnt matter.)

```
void TaskQueue::push_pack(std::shared_ptr<Task> t)
{
    std::lock_guard<SpinLock> lock(m_spin);
    m_tasks.push_back(t);
    //notify that there is one more task, so one thread can work now
    m_cond.notify_one();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `push_back` be protected as well?

Comment: It doens't change something if i also lock this with a mutex. I already tried this. Sorry that i didn't mention it.

Comment: You should protect it anyway, and with the same mutex as the `pop_front` function, or you could could have multiple threads modifying the list at the same time. And if it doesn't help, do you use iterators to loop over the list somewhere else without protection?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You are my hero for today! You were right that i need to add the `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);` to the `push_back`. Thats quit a stupid misstake of me but i wasnt sure if i can use the same lock here. But sure a different lock doesnt make sense as you said! Please add this as answer so you get a reward for this fix.